# How can I redirect to different views based on user role or privilege in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, web, eloquent, laravel-8

I put the function below in the **LoginController** class to redirect users to different views, and when after login I got this **419|expired page**.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {
    if ($user->PRIVILEGE == 'C') {
        return redirect()->route('/users');
    } else if ($user->PRIVILEGE == 'B') {
        return redirect('/blog');
    } else {
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: better to use Auth guard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First put this in your **LoginController** class: **use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;**
2. comment out this line **protected $redirectTo =...**
   and also add this function in the **LoginController** class:

   **public function redirectPath()**
   {

   ```
   if(Auth::user()->privilege =='C'){

     return '/users';
   }
   if(Auth::user()->privilege=='B'){

     return '/blog';
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score -1):

Have a look inside the `handle` method in `app\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` you will see that after a user has passed the Auth check they are greeted with a redirect.

This class was designed to redirect users to the correct `landing` page once authenticated.

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            if ($user->PRIVILEGE == 'C') {
                return redirect()->route('/users');
            }
            if ($user->PRIVILEGE == 'B') {
                return redirect('/blog');
            } 
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: when use your answer it take me to '/home' I do not want to go to '/home'.

Comment: put some print_r();'s in and see what $user is and where you're returning